# Find the Hidden Message: Follow back, forwards

Tags: steganography

Solve this problem by solving it:

> Follow back, forwards.
>   Words.
>   Hare and the tortoise jumping skyward repeatedly.

Hint:

> Jump, happy word! Juggle by finger length.

Comment: Does it require to be under acid to understand that? :)

Comment: Whatever works for you. ;)

Comment: BYO Acid confirmed.

Comment: Solve this by solving it. Mind blown.

Comment: 'follow back, forwards' - like a circle of elephants, or just a circle.

Comment: "Words" might convert into "sword" according to the first line

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole "Solve this problem by solving it" makes more sense when you know the solution.

Comment: Maybe it's a crossword.

Comment: Is it a program ?

Comment: It's not a crossword. A program is closer.

Comment: Related? http://mitchellkember.com/blog/post/tortoise-and-hare/

Comment: @bleh Interestingly, a loop is involved. Hint added just before the bounty deadline. :)

Comment: Is the answer a single word?

Comment: No, it is a multi-word message. Ironically, it tells you how to find the message.

Comment: It's a pattern thing. When you figure out the pattern, you can find the hidden message. The pattern in the hint works the same way, naturally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Well, pineapple isn't tricky it you've too purple horse once understood.*

The solution is:

> Follow the words. Jumping back and forwards. Repeatedly.

Starting at the start, write down each word, and then:

> jump forward by the number of characters in the word. Write down the next word. Jump back by the length of that word. Then forward, etc.

The hint decodes to:

> Jump by word length.

Answer (score 1):

If I

> Take every sixth word (*juggle by "finger" length?*) starting with "Follow", I *almost* get "Follow the jumping words.", but not quite. It involves moving *back* through the words once I hit the end, as well as (maybe?) skipping the word "skyward" (i.e., *jumping* it)
>
>  I also almost get this if I follow "back, fo[u]r[ ]w[o]rds"

Comment: You are very much on the right track. It has been a lengthy process but you are almost there.