# What Road and What Story?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, steganography

Professor O'Brien is missing from his laboratory. So is the elaborate contraption he has been working 
on for months. Paranoid about security, Professor O'Brien has not confided the nature of his experiments 
to anyone. It is known that he has been consuming vast amounts of electricity. Inspector Bostwick has
been called in to investigate. The only things he has uncovered that might possibly be clues are
the Professor's half-eaten dinner (a slab of ground meat covered in Indian spices) and a note in an 
envelope labelled "Do Si Do".

The note reads as follows:

> Take steps: these all repeat.
>   It's "then" then "prime" and "and".
>   Just words left.
>   A. numbers these: "the, all, step".
>   A. to remove to reverse the jump, right?

The only one of Professor O'Brien's colleagues having a name that begins with A, Dr. Adams,
claims to know nothing of the professor's work, the professor's whereabouts, or the meaning
of the note.

**Can you explain the note? Can you answer the questions in the title?**

Hints:

> 41, Stephen King, ice cream, type of dance

Comment: [This is Do Si Do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-si-do)

Comment: Do Si Do can be both a type of dance and ([apparently](http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/do-si-dos-ice-cream-truffles)) ice cream. Can't find any connection to Stephen King or 41 though.

Comment: Related (semi-spoilers): [One of Hugh's previous puzzles](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/27643/5208)

Comment: @Alconja I liked that one. But please tell me you didn't research my past puzzles to solve this.

Comment: @HughMeyers - No, not at all. Just after I solved this one, it's structure reminded me of that one and I went looking for it, only to discover it was also your creation. You clearly have a tangled mind. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly, **Do Si Do** hints at a couple of things:

> 1. It's a dance move that involves *circling* around
>  2. It's a move that's generally seen in *square* dances

So if we take words from the note based on:

> Indexed positions that are *square numbers*, we extract:
>  ***Take*** steps these **all** repeat It's then then **prime** and and Just words left A **numbers** these the all step A to remove to **reverse** the jump right
>
>  Or:
>  **Take all prime numbers, reverse**

Then following that instruction:

> So, indexing *prime numbers*:
>  *Take **steps** **these** all **repeat** It's **then** then prime and **and** Just **words** left A numbers **these** the **all** step A to **remove** to reverse the jump right*
>
>  Or (when reversed as per initial instruction):
>  **Remove all these words and then repeat these steps**

As per this new instruction we:

> Remove all the used words to give:
>  *It's then and Just left A the step A to to the jump right*
>
>  Then repeat the initial instructions to give:
>  **It's just a** *(from squares)* **jump to the left, and then** *(from reversed primes)*
>  Leaving us with:
>  **a step to the right** (though it arguably should've been "*A right the step to*" to continue following the pattern...)

Now that text is obviously a reference to:

> [*Time Warp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Warp_(song)) from [*The Rocky Horror Show*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rocky_Horror_Show), which is also hinted at by other clues sprinkled throughout the text (thanks @tmpearce), such as:
>   - The Professor's name is **O'Brien** and The Rocky Horror Show was written by Richard **O'Brien**
>   - The "half-eaten dinner" is covered in "**Indian spices**" and the lead actor in Rocky Horror (both stage and film) is Tim **Curry**
>   - The "half-eaten dinner" is a "**slab of ground meat**", which may hint at **Meat Loaf**'s role in The Rocky Horror [Picture] Show
>   - The inspector's name is **Bostwick**, which mirror's actor Barry **Botswick** who stared in TRHPS
>   - The colleague Dr. **Adams** may hint at Jonathan **Adams** another star of TRH[P]S

So I'm assuming that "the elaborate contraption [Professor O'Brien] has been working on for months" is:

> A time machine. And more specifically, our Professor is in fact *the* Richard O'Brien" and he's gone back in time to the early 1970's in order to write and produce **The Rocky Horror Show** (the *Story* from the title), which will run at the **Chelsea Classic Cinema on Kings Road** (the *Road* from the title) from '73 to '79.

Comment: Wow. I'd got as far as picking out all prime-indexed words in the original verse, but the layers in this are just amazing!

Comment: Lyrics of the Rocky Horror Picture Show are by Richard **O'Brien**, and the movie stars Barry **Bostwick** and Tim **Curry** (Indian spices) and features **Meatloaf** (slab of ground meat). And perhaps the road is "Broadway" for the musical...

Comment: @tmpearce - Noticed the Tim Curry connection, but not the others, so it seemed tenuous at best. But combined with the others it makes more sense. Though, I don't think it'd be broadway, since it's a british production.. more likely Kings Road which was it's primary home from ['73 to '79](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rocky_Horror_Show)... will update.

Comment: Very good! I was completely on the wrong track here; I tried to pair the words up in two lines and make them do a weaving dancing figure - after all the first 14 words end with "left", the next 14 with "right". Yeah, that didn't get me anywhere, of course. `:)`

Comment: Good work @Alconja, as usual! A bounty well deserved :)

Comment: Congratulations! And apologies to the female lead whose name I was not clever enough to disguise and insert. In October of this year there is to be a remake of the longest-running theatrical release in film history, 41 years after its premier. It seemed only fitting to mark the occasion.